# how to use key board hotkey to run with powershell like right click mouse and choose run with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a problem to run a ps1 file with powershell with using hotkey , normally we run ps1 file by using right click mouse and choose run with powershell , but that is too slow for me , so I like to use hotkey to make it , if any expert know the answer please help . Thanks

Comment: Would the hotkey always run the same file? If not, how do you expect the file to be run to get passed?

Comment: Normally I will use key board select the file then run the file , but powershell ps1 file i cannot make like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way I have found to do this is to create a simple BAT file:

Open notepad and enter the below

```
start powershell c:\scripts\powershell-script.ps1
```

Changing the `c:\scripts\powershell-script.ps1` bit for the location of your script.

Then file > save-as > other files. Name it as "start script.bat" or something. You can then just double click the BAT file and this will run your script.

There may be better ways, but this is the simplest and easiest way I found that is very painless.

Comment: i think he wants to use the hotkey to open any script directly with powershell, not one specific

Comment: Can this use for run ps1 file with powershell.exe at network share ? For example : start powershell \\file-server\scripts\powershell-script.ps1

Comment: Forgot to tell you my system is 64bit

Comment: @weechengyong I believe so, but haven't tested this myself. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Sorry forgot to feedback

I already found other way can do this , just using vba programming or visual basic or other programming can make this 
Thx guys